# xcode 6 ios 8 uiimageview

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, ios8, xcode6

I want to update my old app for ios 8 and new devices. So i just tested my app on xcode 6 ios 8 simulator. Everything was good except one thing. I have a button in my app and when i press it it should open an image on an uiimageview. It is working on ios 7.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)circlebutton1:(UIButton *)sender{

     NSUInteger index = [circleImages indexOfObject:_circlebutton1.accessibilityLabel];

     if(changenumber != 1){

        NSLog(@"#1");

        if(_rectangle1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyslot.png"]){
            NSLog(@"#2");
            _rectangle1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[rectangleImages objectAtIndex:index]];
            _rectangle1.accessibilityLabel = rectangleImages[index];
        }

        ...

}
```

First nslog appears but the second one not. So the problem is about if statement i guess.
 But i can't figure out. Hope you guys help me.

Best Regards,

Taha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i realised that i missed a little part of documentation about uiimage.

"You must use isEqual: to correctly test for equality"

```
if([_rectangle1.image isEqual: [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyslot.png"]])
```